# Pregunta sobre atributo de sql Tipo Bit

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas tardes muchachos, tengo una duda sobre este tipo "Bit". Tengo que insertar unos datos a una tabla desde c# pero uno de esos datos es de tipo bit.. que tipo de dato desde c# equivale el de tipo bit en sql server?

Comment: Buenas!! Equivale a un **Boolean**! [Más info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Nico tu comentario deberías ponerlo como respuesta, de esta forma vamos alimentando la base de conocimientos y manteniendo la salud de las P-R del sitio ;)

Comment: Conceptualmente es un boolean, aunque al convertir el valor de SQL server, yo utilizaria un tipo byte de C#.

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la ventaja de usar un `byte` en lugar de un `bool`? ¿o por qué lo prefieres de esa manera?

Comment: el boolean solo puede ser true o false, no un 1 o 0, como el bit en SQL SERVER. Un byte puede representar un 1 o 0.